# Prevent scrollbars from popping up

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a parallax master script to move divs around based on mouse location. The problem is, sometimes one of the elements goes too far and browsers scrollbars show up. Is there a way to disable this with css or js? Thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1z0zmdK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide scrollbars with `overflow: hidden;`. Set this on the container on which scrollbars appear.

**Example:**

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden